# Updating multiple rows in single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I need to update newly added column(store the sum of all items of the invoice) with result from subquery which generates more than one rows. I added new column to *Invoice* table.

```
ALTER TABLE Invoice
ADD ItemsSum int NULL
```

I tried following query but it gave error because of multiple results

```
UPDATE Invoice
SET ItemsSum = (SELECT SUM(Amount)
               FROM InvoiceItem it
               INNER JOIN Invoice i ON it.InvoiceID = i.ID
               GROUP BY i.ID)
```

How to achieve this correctly in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

You can use correlated subquery :

```
UPDATE Invoice
     SET ItemsSum = (SELECT SUM(it.Amount) 
                     FROM InvoiceItem it 
                     WHERE it.InvoiceID = Invoice.ID
                    );
```

`ItemsSum` will be invalid if underlying invoice amount will be change.

Answer (score 0):

correlated is :

```
UPDATE Invoice
     SET ItemsSum = (SELECT SUM(invc.Amount) 
                     FROM InvoiceItem invc 
                     WHERE invc.InvoiceID = Invoice.ID
                     GROUP BY Invoice.ID;
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yogesh's answer is correct, but if you like, you can also do this using an explicit aggregation:

```
UPDATE i
    SET ItemsSum = ii.sumAmount
FROM Invoice i LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT ii.InvoiceID, SUM(Amount) as sumAmount
      FROM InvoiceItem it
      GROUP BY ii.InvoiceID
     ) ii
     ON ii.InvoiceID = i.ID
```